# Null pointer check via "myPtr > 0"

Tags: c++, null, comparison, null-pointer, null-check

In some legacy code I came across the following **null pointer check**.

```cpp
if( myPtr > 0 ) {
...
}
```

Are there any technical risks of checking for a null pointer via this if-check?

Comment: IIRC this is technically invalid: you can only compare pointers that point to the same array/object. Comparing unrelated pointers for order is invalid.

Comment: @KonradRudolph iirc comparing to null is an exception.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number No, it isn’t. Equality comparison is valid between any two pointers. Order comparison isn’t.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Even if you use `std::greater`?

Comment: I wonder if that code snippet is just a typo.

Comment: Conceivably, a pointer could be *smaller* than 0. ;-) Even if this compiled. The only guarantee for an object is that its address is *not equal* to nullptr.

Comment: @KonradRudolph equality comparison is not valid between a pointer-to-object and a pointer-to-one-past-end https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#3 *If one pointer represents the address of a complete object, and another pointer represents the address one past the last element of a different complete object,72 the result of the comparison is unspecified.* https://godbolt.org/z/4aqGMWGfq

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I was thinking the same thing. There's no guarantee that [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/GxM8jaMqE) will print _"greater"_. It could just as well have printed _"less"_,

Comment: @TedLyngmo Why would `std::greater` be any different?

Comment: @KonradRudolph *`std::greater` is different* https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater A specialization of std::greater for any pointer type yields the implementation-defined strict total order, even if the built-in > operator does not.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili “unspecified” ≠ “invalid”!

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Ah, good to know.

Comment: @KonradRudolph for all intents and purposes, you shouldn't rely on unspecified behavior :)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Re "equality comparison is not valid between a pointer-to-object and a pointer-to-one-past-end": it is entirely valid (and performed all the time when iterating arrays) for pointer to object and pointer one-past *the same object*. The quoted passage mentions "the address one past the last element of a **different** complete object". (Conceivably, that one-past-the-end pointer could point to an adjacent object and hence compare equal.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica my point stands that there exists at least one case where equality comparing two well-defined pointers yields unspecified result.

Comment: related: [Is a pointer considered an unsigned value in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48429021/995714), [Pointer comparisons in C. Are they signed or unsigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6702161/995714). Pointers can be compared as signed or unsigned internally, that's one of the reasons why it's UB

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, you mentioned that "a pointer could be smaller than 0". Can you give an **explicit example** how a pointer can smaller than 0?

Comment: They can compare unequal, while ordered comparison using >, >=, <, <= invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Given that p is a pointer is "p > nullptr" well-formed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26590267/1708801)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: In the language actually processed by clang and gcc, an equality comparison between a just-past pointer and a pointer to the next object may not only yield true or false in arbitrary fashion, but may also cause surrounding code to behave nonsensically as well.

Comment: Very similar code to this caused problems when people started exceeding 2GB of address space in 32-bit code. If you did this kind of thing on pointers using signed types for the comparisons, pointers to the second half of the address space might compare less than zero. It's wrong for the same reason checking if a `char` is less than 0 is wrong because you're just hoping that `char` is signed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It's interesting to note that on 16-bit x86, even though ptrdiff_t was generally signed 16 bits, objects over 32,768 bytes were common.  For any `char *p,*q;` that identified parts of the same object, the value of `q-p` would be such that `p+(q-p)` would equal `q`, since computing `(q-p)` would result in numerical wraparound, but adding that value to `p` would cause a wraparound in the opposite direction.  The Standard didn't consider such possibilities, but treating things that way was much more practical than a 32-bit `ptrdiff_t` would have been.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ordered comparison between a pointer and an integer is ill-formed in C++ (even when the integer is a null pointer constant such as it is in this case). The risk is that compilers are allowed to, and do, refuse to compile such code.

---

You can rewrite it as either of these:

```
if(myPtr != nullptr)
if(myPtr)
```

Comment: Side-note, it does compile as C code https://godbolt.org/z/qjvs77W3b

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Not with `-pedantic-errors` though. Some compilers, including GCC, accept some ill-formed programs by default.

Answer (score 19):

`0` is a NULL constant.  So this is equivalent to `ptr > (void*)0`.

Problem is that `>` on pointers in C++ is only valid for pointers into the same object or array.  This rule originated from back when relatively insane stuff like segmented memory was more common, but it permits optimizations and assumptions by the compiler.

For example, suppose `px` is a pointer into an array, and it currently points at the first element.  Then `px>py` is true unless `py` is also a pointer to the first element. Or, if `px` is a pointer to one-past-the-end of an array, then `px<py` is always false.

Using that kind of knowledge, compilers can understand refactor and rewrite loop bounds, which in turn can let the compiler produce much faster code.

But this also means that `px>py` could be true in one spot and not in another, because the compiler can prove a fact about `py` in one spot but not another.

In short, be very careful about pointer comparisons.

Meanwhile, equality between null and any other pointer is well defined.

Also `std::less` is guaranteed to be well behaved, and agree with `<` when `<` is defined; this permits maps of pointers to work.

In this case, the proper rewrite is:

```
if(myPtr!=nullptr)
```

which will fail to compile if `myPtr` isn't a pointer, or

```
if(myPtr)
```

which has the risk that if `myPtr` is a signed number type you just changed behaviour.  I'd do the first.

Comment: _This rule originated from back when relatively insane stuff like segmented memory was more common_ => Of note, modern architectures like CHERI are "effectively" segments, and comparing pointers of various provenance may end up triggering faults.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, the comparison is invalid so the behavior depends on compiler. It's possible that many OSes consider pointers as signed because they split the address space into halves with the negative one belongs to the kernel so compilers there may emit signed comparisons for `myPtr > 0`

There are a couple of cases I've seen compilers consider pointers as signed but I couldn't find them right now. But one notable example is the [`POINTER_SIGNED` and `POINTER_UNSIGNED` macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) in Windows which resolves to [`__sptr` and `__uptr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/sptr-uptr?view=msvc-170)

See also

- [comparing pointer to a negative value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19139258/995714)
- [Must allocated memory address be positive in user space of all platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68576493/995714)
- [Pointer comparisons in C. Are they signed or unsigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6702161/995714)